# Apple App Store shows Universal size of the app rather than individual installation size of app

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, app-store

I have recently update my app on App Store and after it rolls out on app store, the size of the app it reflects on the App Store is universal size rather than the actual individual installation size of the app. For example for iPhone-7 my app installation size is 39.3 MB but it shows 70.3 MB on App Store which is universal size. Has anybody face this issue.

Comment: Im also facing this issue.

Comment: Are you check app-size on browser? I found that app-size is shown correctly on respective iPhones devices.

Comment: @AnkitJayaswal I have visited App Store with different devices and found every device shown universal size.

Comment: Have you used vector images or png images?

Comment: I have downloaded the app. Downloaded size is correct. Just showing wrong size in App store.

Comment: @AnkitJayaswal vector images with pdf conversion. See it has not happened with my previous build. i content with apple developer support and they are on it.

Comment: @ChanOnly123 same here. do let me know if you found any solution

Comment: @VinayakPal, I think it might be the issue with vector images. I used vector images in one of my project and checked the contents of .ipa file and found that `assets.car` package is the reason for larger build-size. And this `assets.car` folder decreased to significant size when used png images. I don't why - but Apple   should have some mechanism to fetch needed size of image in case of vector images.

Comment: Same issue encountered. I was wondering if it's a bug or feature?

Comment: I also see this issue. Has anybody found out, if this is iOS 12 only or also happening on other iOS versions? I made the build with Xcode 10 and the new build system, maybe this is the reason. Anybody also saw this with older Xcode versions or the legacy build system?

Comment: @SimonC. Kindly check your build size on App Store again. if it's hasn't change then follow the latest answer I post below

Comment: 9to5Mac reports that this issue has been fixed on October 1, 2018: https://9to5mac.com/2018/09/26/app-store-bug-large-app-size/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got the solution by connecting App Store Executive from my developer profile.

Following are the steps to get help from Apple developers account :

Step 1 : Login to developer account on: https://developer.apple.com/contact

Step 2 : Select [App Setup & Distribution] section

Step 3 : Select [App, Build & version management] section

Step 4 : Now There are 2 option (Call or Email) to contact for help. I prefer call over email

Step 5 : If you select call you will get a call back from apple representative and you can communicate with them regarding this issue or you can do same with email as well.

Step 6 : After discussion they will escalate your issue to their engineering team and sooner or later your issue will be resolved.

After discussion I realised App Store solved this issue soon every possible app that might include each and every app. If it's not you can follow above mention steps to resolve your issue.